# Screen becomes yellow if white software opened

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, colors, windows-10-v1903

Below is the picture of desktop with white wallpaper. It is yellow, if I open a bright white application like google chrome/ ms edge it becomes very yellowish. If open nothing it is lesser yellow than earlier and if I open dark/ black apps like camera it becomes white like normal.

[image: Desktop with pure white background]

Physical Appearance:
[image: How it appears]

In the above image you can see that there is yellow tint everywhere except around camera and any other application that has black UI

I tried these things

1. Turning off night light (already)
2. Restarting My Pc ( I restarted several times)
3. Reinstalling Latest Driver from Nvidia Website Graphics Card Driver. (Complete reinstallation)
4. Setting Color management to sRGB IEC61966-2.1 and making it to default.
5. Turning off colour filter and High Contrast in ease of access(already).
   Further details

Nvidia driver version : 457.30

Windows Version 10 1903 18362.1198 Build

While booting the blue windows logo appears well but as soon as it started windows it becomes yellow tinted.

**Update**

It is IPS Panel so there should be no problem
Now physical apperance is added

It is desktop and the boot logo motherboard brand logo and windows logo looks everything fine

I use VGA Cable

Comment: Your picture shows pure white. What type of screen is it?

Comment: Screenshots don't reflect physical appearance of your screen.

Comment: Is that a desktop computer or a laptop? If it's a desktop, have you tried with another screen? Or this screen with another computer? If it's a laptop, have you tried with an external screen?

Comment: How is your screen connected to your computer? VGA or HDMI or DisplayPort or…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VGA is dead and you shouldn’t be using it unless absolutely necessary. Your screenshot is 1920×1080, which is in the upper regions of what VGA can support at all. It can work perfectly fine with good cables and good VGA sources (your PC/graphics card) and displays, but most modern VGA hardware is anything but good.

Why did it work without problems while booting? Because the resolution is much lower during that time, typically 1024×768 or less.

Because of how VGA encodes the image information, bad signal quality can lead to vertical artifacts like you’re seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. It works well with HDMI Cable. So it looks like there is a problem in my VGA cable.

Very sorry for wasting your Precious time.

As suddenly it stopped working and as the boot logo (motherboard logo) and windows booting logo looked well (I think it worked as it had black around) I thought it was a problem in software.